# Post int as part of method but get No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI error

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a MVC WebAPI controller, which takes in an id, which it creates a record with in the database and then returns. However, I keep getting an error.

In my testAPI controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage OpenSession(int id)
{
    //Logic of post in here never gets hit
}
```

However when I try and post to the API I get the following response:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54388/api/testAPI/OpenSession/'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'testAPI' that matches the request."}
```

I have changed my routing to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/"
);
```

I am trying to post to: `http://localhost:54388/api/testAPI/OpenSession/` with the value id in the payload. However I think it is expecting it in the URL - can someone please point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebApi is problematic when you try to POST only a single parameter. I remember I had the same problem. There are many ways to sort this out, but the one that works every time is to have a model instead of an int:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage OpenSession(OpenSessionParameters parameters)
{
    //Logic of post in here never gets hit
}

public class OpenSessionParameters
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you insist on not having a class, you can try this: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/
I have used this for a bit, but ended up replacing all of `[FromBody]` arguments to models - works more reliable.

Comment: Your parameter class approach seems like a good idea. However the Id on OpenSessionParameters is always set to 0. I am sending the JSON: {"OpenSessionParameters": {"Id":"123"}}

Comment: try sending just `{"Id":"123"}`, without name of the class

Comment: Yes - that did the trick. Why does it not expect it in a 'parameter' object? What happens when I have multiple parameters, perhaps each with an id object, how will it know which one it relates to? Thanks.

Comment: It would not bind if you have multiple models with `Id` in them (why would you do that?). And I would not recommend using multiple models in posted data: one post action - one model. But if you really want to, you can implement your custom data binder: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api