# Web API Ajax calling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Here is my js code to call custom web api method..

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/AdminAPI/IndustryPost/?industryName='+addNewIndustryName,
        type: 'Post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',       
        success: function (response) {
           // response code.
        }
    });
```

this is working fine but in case i am using 'data' tag to send data, its not working. like THE FOLLOWING.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/api/AdminAPI/IndustryPost',
        type: 'Post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { 'industryName': addNewIndustryName },
        success: function (response) {
           // response code.
        }
    });
```

WebApiConfig is config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

here is my api method

```
    [ActionName("IndustryPost")]
    public void AddIndustry(string industryName)
    {
        //code here
    }
```

While testing with fiddler second code request result to 404 error. While accessing web API method directly from URL works fine.

Answer::

After doing R'N'D on this topic i came to know that there is a issue in web API parameter binding. So, what either we can use [formUri] tag or we can have a model class. like this

public class IndustryName
    {
        public string Industryname { get; set; }
    }

and in web api method

public void IndustryPost(IndustryName industryName)
        {
            // 
        }

No change needed in jquery.

Here this article explain it all 
[Post int as part of method but get No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815268/post-int-as-part-of-method-but-get-no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change below line

```
data: { 'industryName': addNewIndustryName }
```

to

```
data: '{ industryName:'+ addNewIndustryName +'}'
```

and also make sure that, addNewIndustryName is global variable and accessible.

Or you can simply assign variable without curly braces like below

```
data: 'industryName='+ addNewIndustryName
```

Comment: is there any error in console? ... can you share jsfiddle for this

Comment: as you said before sending data object in ajax it was working fine, so can you please check if addNewIndustryName object is accessible to jquery ajax call

Comment: Yes its accessible... in ajax body i hv used firebug and alert msg itself to confirm.

Comment: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:XXXX/api/AdminAPI/IndustryPost/'. this is the message shown in error function.

Comment: see this posts, may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+HTTP+resource+was+found+that+matches+the+request+URI  I don't know much about asp .net :(

Answer (score 0):

here you are missing a quote in your ajax url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/AdminAPI/IndustryPost/', //<----here put a / slash at the end
    type: 'Post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json', //<-------you can use json
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { 'industryName': addNewIndustryName },
    success: function (response) {
       // response code.
    }
});
```

Comment: my bad, i posted it in hurry. But in my code its correct.

Comment: okay! try to change your url with this `url: '/api/AdminAPI/IndustryPost/',` add a `/` in the end.